# Can't get Outlook to respect td height

Tags: html-email, gravity-forms-plugin

I have been digging all over and experimenting with different attributes, but I am still no closer to getting Outlook (v2005) to respect `<td>` cell height. I have a simple table being used through Gravity forms in Wordpress which is handling all the overhead. The `<td>` is set o have the `mso-line-height-rule` line height and font size as mentioned several times elsewhere, but comes out as below.

[image]

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="80px" width="80" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color: red; height: 30px; font-size: 30px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 30px;  padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;" height="30">                                                        
                Hello
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.
Screenshot of Outlook version:
[image]

Comment: Outlook 2005? Is that even a thing? 

But what is your aim here? What "cell spacing" is not being respected here? Is the width or height of the `<td>` wrong?

Comment: Yes it is apparently a thing. Version screenshot attached and as per the title it is the height I am having trouble with.

Comment: Oh right, this is 365. 2005 / Build 12827.20268 is like some internal version number I guess.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Might need a more complete code snippet. However, width="80px" is not right, just use width="80"; also, Outlook does not respect !important and will remove those styles completely. So don't use !important. I saw someone else say if you are using mso-line-height-rule set that *after* the line-height style, so you could try that also.